# count pattern, based on wildcard in R data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
Type    cat1
A   NA
B   NA
C   NA
D   Huvec,2_Weak_Promoter;NHLF,2_Weak_Promoter;NHEK,3_Poised_Promoter
E   Huvec,2_Weak_Promoter;NHLF,2_Weak_Promoter
F   HepG2,2_Weak_Promoter
G   SK.MUS62,6_TssD2
```

And I would want to count the number of times the following pattern repeats in each rows of column_cat1

> string1,string2;

and the expected output is

```
Type    Count
A   NA
B   NA
C   NA
D   3
E   2
F   1
G   1
```

I have got no clue of how to use regex pattern or str_split in this.. can someone help me out..

Thanks
Mur

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stringr` package and `str_count`,

```
library(stringr)
str_count(df$cat1, ',')
#[1] NA NA NA  3  2  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

@sotos answer is much cleaner, but here is a base R solution:

```
cat1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Huvec,2_Weak_Promoter;NHLF,2_Weak_Promoter;NHEK,3_Poised_Promoter",
          "Huvec,2_Weak_Promoter;NHLF,2_Weak_Promoter", "HepG2,2_Weak_Promoter", 
          "SK.MUS62,6_TssD2")

myCount <- sapply(strsplit(cat1, split=";"), FUN=length)
```

This relies on the pattern that every entry is separated by the semi-colon, ";".